# Regular expression: replace select for select count

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to define a regular expression to get a `select count(*)` from any select query. This is my code:

```
preg_replace("/(select{1}) (.)+ (from{1}) (.)*/im", "'$1 count(*) $3 $4'", "select columna, columnb from table1 join table2 where a=b", -1, $count);
```

It's not doing that bad except that it's returning only last character after the "from", this is:

```
select count(*) from b
```

It should be

```
select count(*) from table1 join table2 where a=b
```

After the "from" can be any character string, also empty one, and the whole query could be a multiline string.

Can you help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of `(.)*` this would capture the last matching char in 4th group.
It should be `(.*)`

A better regex would be

```
^\s*select .+ from (.*)$
```

replace with

```
select count(*) from $1
```

Comment: Oops, I marked answer,but sorry, it doesn't replace in this query `select C.id, C.name, C.description, CR.name as code_rated, S.name as segment, 'Users' as users
           from calif C
        left join code_rated CR on CR.id = C.id_code
        left join calif_segment CS on CS.id_calif=C.id
        left join segment S on S.id=CS.id_segment`

Comment: @K.Weber works for me..does your input contain multiple select queries.

Comment: that didn't work because you were using  multiline option `m` use dot all option i.e `s`